# dh_install not finding files that clearly exist

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, packaging, deb

Running `debuild -us -uc` to build a package I'm working on, `dh_install` complains about missing files. Running it on it's own, it prints the same error messages:

```
$ dh_install
/home/felix/work/my_app/debian/install: 1: /home/felix/work/my_app/debian/install: execute.py: not found
/home/felix/work/my_app/debian/install: 2: /home/felix/work/my_app/debian/install: module1: not found
```

Though I'm in the correct directory, and the files are clearly there:

```
$ pwd
/home/felix/work/my_app
$ ll
total 56K
[...]
-rwxrwxr-x 1 felix felix  20K Dez  6 10:35 execute.py
[...]
drwxrwxr-x 4 felix felix 4,0K Dez  1 19:10 module1
[...]
```

And here's my `debian/install`:

```
execute.py usr/lib/my-cool-app
module1 usr/lib/my-cool-app
```

*What am I doing wrong?* This worked a day ago, and I changed nothing in this directory since then:

```
$ git status
On branch debian_package
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Additional info:

```
$ dpkg -s debhelper | grep Version
Version: 9.20131227ubuntu1
$ cat debian/compat
9
```

Comment: What version of `debhelper` do you have? Did it get upgraded overnight by any chance? What’s your package’s compatibility level (`debian/compat`)?

Comment: @StephenKitt What is compatibility level?

Comment: @StephenKitt Added it to the question. Looks reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly you are encountering this [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=901715) in dh-install, as I mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047319/841303) Remove the executable bit in your `.install` file:

`chmod -x debian/*.install`

Answer (score 1):

Your `debian/install` file is wrong. You should use:

```
execute.py usr/lib/my-cool-app
module1 usr/lib/my-cool-app
```

Note: `usr/lib` without a initial slash.

Such files should be put into the package "root" (AKA DESTDIR), to be ready to be packed, so you should use relative paths (relative to "DESTDIR"). Your file causes the build system to move the files into your system `/usr`, so such files are not found into the temporary location.

Comment: That is very true, but it didn't help. I re-ran debuild and still get the exact same error, even after running `debuild clean` before.

Comment: How many packages should be created by your source? Try to use debian/<package>.install . You should list your files (and not just the directory) for the module1 (not sure it is a requirements, but it is a lot safer). And you should use python helper to install python modules (or such modules will not "compiled"

Comment: Just one. I'm also looking into setuptools right now and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue in WSL. The real reason is that the `dh_install` is too smart for me ))

But I've found a workaround solution which mentioned in [debian mail archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1610965.html)
So the result could be:

debian/install

```
#!/bin/bash
echo execute.py usr/lib/my-cool-app
echo module1 usr/lib/my-cool-app
```